# Oracle confunde Tablespace con usuario

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

estoy trabajando con Oracle con el usuario SYSTEM que viene por defecto, he creado mi tablespace con el siguiente código:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE GOYA DATAFILE
    'C:\GOYA\GOYA\GOYA.DBF' SIZE 7168M AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 100M MAXSIZE UNLIMITED
    LOGGING 
    ONLINE
    PERMANENT
    EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL AUTOALLOCATE
    BLOCKSIZE 8K
    SEGMENT SPACE MANAGEMENT AUTO
    FLASHBACK ON;
```

Todo bien por ahora, se crea el tablespace satisfactoriamente y empiezo con la creación de tablas con el siguiente código:

```
CREATE TABLE GOYA.MANTENIMIENTO
(
ID_MANTENIMIENTO NUMBER NOT NULL,
COD_TIPO_MTO NUMBER NOT NULL,
COD_EXPEDIENTE VARCHAR2(25 BYTE),
COD_CONTRATO VARCHAR2(25 BYTE),
TIPO_PROCEDIMIENTO_ADJUDICADO NUMBER,
COD_DEPARTAMENTO NUMBER,
COD_UNIDAD NUMBER,
COD_RESPONSABLE NUMBER,
TXT_DESCRIPCION VARCHAR2(2000 BYTE),
DES_EMPRESA VARCHAR2(255 BYTE),
NUM_IMPORTE NUMBER(12,2),
FE_INI_CONTRATO DATE,
FE_FIN_CONTRATO DATE,
CHK_PRORROGA CHAR(1 BYTE),
FE_INI_PRORROGA DATE,
FE_FIN_PRORROGA DATE,
TXT_OBSERVACIONES VARCHAR2(2000 BYTE),

CHK_ACTIVO CHAR(1 BYTE),
FE_CREA_REG DATE,
FE_MODI_REG DATE,
COD_MOD_USU VARCHAR2(8 BYTE),
PALABRA_CLAVE VARCHAR2(2000 BYTE)
)
TABLESPACE GOYA
PCTUSED 0
PCTFREE 10
INITRANS 1
MAXTRANS 255
STORAGE (
INITIAL 64K
NEXT 1M
MINEXTENTS 1
MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED
PCTINCREASE 0
BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
)
LOGGING
NOCOMPRESS
NOCACHE
NOPARALLEL
MONITORING;
```

A la hora de ejecutar la consulta de creación me arroja el siguiente error relacionado con el usuario refiriéndose al tablespace

```
Informe de error -
ORA-01918: el usuario 'GOYA' no existe
01918. 00000 -  "user '%s' does not exist"
*Cause:    User does not exist in the system.
*Action:   Verify the user name is correct.
```

No entiendo muy bien el concepto de este error, soy novato en Oracle pero he trabajado con SQL, nunca he visto que en sentencias SQL el segundo parametr de creación sea un usuario.

Gracias por adelantado y un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes conocer un poco la estructura de almacenamiento de ORACLE para identificar el problema.

> Oracle define “esquema” como la colección de estructuras lógicas que corresponden a los datos almacenados, 
>   y crea un nuevo esquema por cada usuario que crea objetos en la base de datos. No hay ninguna relación directa entre tablespace 
>   y esquema, objetos del mismo esquema pueden estar en diferentes tablespaces y un mismo tablespace puede almacenar distintos esquemas.

Ahora bien, volviendo a tu caso creaste un **TABLESPACE** llamado GOYA que no esta asignado a ningun esquema llamado GOYA por lo tango
cuando intestas crear la tabla de esta forma:

```
    CREATE TABLE GOYA.MANTENIMIENTO
 (.....
     )
    TABLESPACE GOYA
```

estas diciendo a ORACLE que debe crear la tabla en el esquema GOYA utilizando el **TABLESPACE** GOYA que perfectamente ya creaste, pero sigue sin existir el esquema.

En este caso debes crear el esquema GOYA y asignarlo al **TABLESPACE** GOYA de esa forma podras ejecutar la sentencia sin problemas.

De esta forma puedes crear el esquema y asignarle todos los provilegios, posterior a esto puedes crear la tabla.

```
    CREATE USER goya IDENTIFIED BY P@ssw0rd DEFAULT TABLESPACE GOYA;
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES TO goya;
```